# Handling Routes in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to get my routes setup for an Area and I have the following URLs that I need to allow:

1. http://localhost/Review/Setup
2. http://localhost/Review/Setup/65
3. http://localhost/Review/Setup/_AjaxGetMember?ReviewId=53

Area = Review | Controller = Setup | Action = Index

Thus for the URLS, they should go to:

1. http://localhost/Review/Setup/Index
2. http://localhost/Review/Setup/Index/65
3. http://localhost/Review/Setup/_AjaxGetMember?ReviewId=53

Here is the route that is currently registered for the area.

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Review_default",
    "Review/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Right now, 1 and 3 in my first list work but 2 does not without putting Index into the URL. What else can I add to make these URLs work so that Index does not have to be added or show up in the URL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I needed to add more routes. There may be a more elegant way to do this but I just tested and it works.

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Review_default",
    "Review/{controller}/{id}",
    new
    {
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    },
    new
    {
        id = @"\d*"
    }
);


context.MapRoute(
    "Review_default2",
    "Review/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    },
    new
    {
        action = @"[A-Za-z]+",
        id = @"\d*"
    }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Review_default3",
    "Review/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    },
    new
    {
        action = @"_[A-Za-z]+",
        id = @"\d*"
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it but that's how I would try it:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Review_setup_directId",
    "Review/Setup/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Setup",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for attempting but that didn't show work on any of the urls.